# Cocos2dx 215 Xcode 5.1 new project not building(clang: error: unknown argument: '-websockets' )

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I started a new project of cocos2dx box2d/normal,both fail to biuild,and i recieve the following error,which is also cropping up in an older project that was working properly.

clang: error: unknown argument: '-websockets' clang: error: unknown argument: '-websockets' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

Cocos2dx is version 2.1.5 and Xcode is version 5.1.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to remove the error BuildSettings->Linking->Other linker FLags Remove -websockets.But i still dont know why its happening.Any suggestions welcome